# Create custom and unlimited Node list per user

Tags: nodes

Lets suppose I have a content type (movie) and I have all movies of Hollywood, I want let  each user can create it's own lists,as example I want to create "My Top 10 movie","My 12 Hot movie","Top fincher","Top Kubric" etc,I know I can do it by `Nodequeue` module,it is good for users that know how work to Drupal Nodequeues ( they should first create a nodequeue add machine Name and its machine name should be unique(select machine name that the other users not create it before) then surf the site and find desire movies and go to nodequeue tab and add that node to it`s nodequeue (really is it too hard for popular users)),But my problem is my user of website is popular web surfers ( not Drupal expert).

Also I can create a content type ( movie lists)  with entity reference,each user can create a node of movie lists, add desire movies by auto complete field and save it.

**I want to know is there another way to create  lists of nodes per user and each user could have serveral lists and can control add/remove nodes to their lists ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look on these modules

1. [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag)
2. [Flag Lists](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag_lists)

Using Flag module users can save nodes in to their bucket
and Flag lists module will make those lists as like folder structure.

Comment: Tnx for your attention, it is seems good but it is rc1 and not  stable module and only used 247 times. my sites is too big with too many user I can't trust this module :( ( flag lists)

Comment: Then You can got for https://www.drupal.org/project/bookmarkorganizer

Comment: I want it was straight forward  popular user,I want is work very easy with simple UX.